# Disable WPF WebBrowser security alert

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I prevent security alert like below in WPF web browser?

Message prompt:

```
Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage.”“This page contains both secure and nonsecure items. Do you want to display the nonsecure items?”
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this remove the alert? http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-display-only-webpage-content-delivered-securely-security-warning-in-ie/

Comment: How can I stop it using code?